# Can iOS8 QuickType show suggestions in more than one language?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

With iOS8's new QuickType feature (predicting words you're likely to type, based on message context, learning frequently used words), is there a way to show predictions in the language of the message?

I'm frequently writing emails in English or German, depending on who I correspond with, and it would be nice if there was a way to have QuickType show suggestions based on the language I'm using in the email or message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, although not automatically. There's currently no way for iOS to detect the language of the message, but you can use multiple keyboards to show predictions in a different language of your choice.

To do this, go to *Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards*. This screen shows a list of keyboards set up on the device. You can use the *Add New Keyboard...* link at the bottom of the screen to add additional keyboards. The keyboards are ordered by language and locale (e.g. *English (Australia)*) - and there's also the *Emoji* keyboard there, for adding smileys and other funny icons to your messages.

Depending on the keyboard, there might be multiple layouts (*QWERTZ*, *QWERTY*, *AZERTY*), which can be switched from the list of selected keyboards by opening the keyboard's details.

Once you have selected an additional keyboard, you will see a new *globe* icon at the bottom left of the keyboard. Pressing the globe icon will switch to the next keyboard, holding the icon for a moment will show all available keyboards, and will also allow to enable/disable the predictions.

Switching to the *English* keyboard will show predictions in English language, while switching to *German* will show predictions in German language. The *Emoji* keyboard doesn't show any preditions :-)